# CouchDB replication error - Only POST allowed

Tags: curl, couchdb, database-replication, nosql

I am trying to replicate a database partially on CouchDB. This is my query that I am implementing using Command Prompt:

```
CURL POST http://localhost:5984/_replicate HTTP/1.1 Content-Type: application/json {"source":"source_db", "target":"target_db", "doc_ids":["00123f8-8uht1-81ia-n1762-81ubas81762121iaj1"]}
```

This is the error:

```
Failed to connect to POST port 80: Timed Out
{"error":"method_not_allowed", "reason":"Only POST allowed"}
```

What is causing the error and how do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your curl command is missing the "-X" before "POST" ... so curl does not identify your "POST" as the method.

see examples with curl in the docs: https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Replication#One-shot_Replication

Comment: Follow up question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35386239/couchdb-illegal-database-name-issue-during-replication-unwanted-added-after-d. Please consider responding